# How to generate extent report in karate framework?

Tags: api, cucumber, karate, extentreports

I need an article on how to generate Extent report in Karate Framework.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619

It is supposed to be done on the Extent side, you can comment / get in touch with the folks on that thread.